How to match the input and output shapes of my data in the encoder model?
I have entered it into the following code:
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, UpSampling1D, Flatten, Dense

# Define the input shape
input_shape = (55, 8)

# Define the number of categories
num_categories = 4

# Define the encoder
encoder = Sequential([
    Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=input_shape),
    MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same'),
    Conv1D(8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')
])

# Define the decoder
decoder = Sequential([
    Conv1D(8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(input_shape[0] // 4, 8)),
    UpSampling1D(2),
    Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    UpSampling1D(2),
    Conv1D(8, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')
])

# Define the autoencoder model
autoencoder = Sequential([encoder, decoder])

# Compile the model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train the autoencoder
autoencoder_history = autoencoder.fit(x_train_exp, x_train_exp, epochs=10, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test_exp, x_test_exp))

I have a two data arrays x_train_exp and x_test_exp of size (18297,55,8) and (7311,55,8). I am trying to create a classifier but the encoder keeps telling me that the shape is not matching.
Each sample has 8 different timeseries data of 55 timestamps.
But I keep getting the error:
Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_8' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 55, 8), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None

for the last line (autoencoder_history line)
